# The Zariski closure of a constructible set is the same as the standard closure?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

> **Question:** Let $X$ be an affine variety over $\Bbb C$, and let $Y\subseteq X$ be a [constructible set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_set_(topology)) (i.e. $Y$ is a finite union of locally closed sets). Is it true that the Zariski closure of $Y$ is the same as the closure of $Y$ in the standard Euclidean topology inherited from the inclusion $X\subseteq\Bbb C^n$?

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1717048/if-an-orbit-g-cdot-x-is-closed-in-the-standard-topology-is-it-zariski-closed) question I asked whether these two closures were the same when $Y$ is the orbit of an algebraic group action. Then, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1717065/304044) answer says that the answer is yes because orbits are constructible sets. However, I don't know a proof of the fact that these orbit closures are the same for constructible sets.

---

If $\bar{Y}^E$ denotes the euclidean closure and $\bar{Y}^Z$ the Zariski one, then it is clear that
$$\bar{Y}^E\subseteq \bar{Y}^Z$$
since the Euclidean topology is finer than the Zariski topology. But for the converse, I am clueless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is true. You probably know that a non-empty Zariski-open set $U\subseteq X$ is Zariski-dense, and it is a standard fact that $U$ is also Euclidean-dense. (See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/15582) mathoverflow answer for a slick proof of that fact.) Assuming this, the proof of your claim is simple:

Wlog, $Y$ is locally closed because the closure of a finite union is the union of the closures. Then, by definition, $Y$ is Zariski-open in $\bar{Y}^Z$ and hence $Y$ is Euclidean-dense in $\bar{Y}^Z$, i.e. $\bar{Y}^E\cap\bar{Y}^Z=\bar{Y}^Z$. Since $\bar{Y}^E\subseteq\bar{Y}^Z$, this concludes the proof.

Comment: Does the second part of your argument not need that $ \bar{Y}^Z$ is irreducible ? Because i do not see why that would be true

Comment: Never mind, i just realized that in such a case we could decompose $\bar{Y}^Z$ into its irreducible components and thus $Y$ into smaller locally closed sets whose closures are then said components.