# How exactly does Zariski-Topology relate to Standard topology on $\Bbb{C}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, zariski-topology

I'm currently self-studying algebraic geometry and I tried to construct some proofs / counterexamples for relations between open / closed sets in Zariski and Standard Topology on $\mathbb{C}$ but I'm not sure about how to do the "open relations":

i) Closed in Zariski $\implies$ Closed in Standard
This should be pretty clear. A closed set in Zariski is finite and any finite set is closed under Standard Topology.

ii) Closed in Standard $\implies$ Closed in Zariski
Not true. Take the ball with radius 1 around the origin (with it's boundary) which is closed in Standard but isn't since it's cardinality is infinite.

Now what about the other implications, i.e. open in Zariski $\implies$ open in Standard and open in Standard $\implies$ Zariski? Do they just follow by De-Morgan laws from the above or are there any good counterexamples that show that these implications are right / wrong?

Are there any interesting connections between closed in Zariski and open in Standard or vice versa?

Comment: I think you just take complements of your set of interest to obtain the analogous statements of i) and ii) (with closed replaced with open).

Comment: There is a much more general statement you can make. Take a set $X$ with two topologies. Suppose every closed set in topology 1 is closed in topology 2, then it should not be a very difficult exercise to show a similar statement for open sets is also true

Answer (score 1):

Your are right, every Zariski-closed set is also closed in the Euclidean topology, but the converse is false in general.

However, for complex algebraic group actions, the orbit is closed in Zariski topology *if and only if* it is closed in Euclidean topology, because orbits are constructible sets. For a proof see Borel's book on linear algebraic groups.

For more details see for example this post:

[The Zariski closure of a constructible set is the same as the standard closure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737286/the-zariski-closure-of-a-constructible-set-is-the-same-as-the-standard-closure?lq=1)